# browser is showing redirected url in address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i am trying to redirect the following URL:

```
<a href="Delhi-NCR/x/y">
```

to another url by following code in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Delhi-NCR/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule Delhi-NCR/(.*)/(.*) pages/examplePage.php?catId=$2 [L,QSA]
```

it is doing fine but browser is showing redirected URL in address bar instead of `Delhi-NCR/x/y`.

What is wrong there?

Comment: That RewriteRule will not actually redirect (it just *rewrites* the internal handling), so you *should* see `Delhi-NCR/..` in your browser. It's unclear why you're not, perhaps some additional redirection takes places in your PHP.

Comment: @deceze it is working fine in local host (xamp in my pc) but when i upload this to actual site it behave as mention in problem statement

Comment: Clear your cache. Furthermore, are you using any frameworks?

Comment: @ Sumurai8, yes i am using boot strap